# Multipart Request in Flutter with MultipartFile.fromBytes

Tags: flutter, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a file to an API with Flutter and the http library.
From a file selector, I get the bytes of the file (a pdf) and create a MultipartRequest as follows:

```
 var request = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', Uri.parse('https://xxx/files'))
    ..fields['grade'] = 'xxx'
    ..fields['candidate'] = 'xxx'
    ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'document', file.bytes!, contentType: MediaType('application', 'pdf')));
var response = await request.send();
```

The request failed, it seems that no binary content is added to this request.
In debug mode I can see that the _stream attribute of the file is null (I am sure that file.bytes contains the file) :
[content of the debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGREF.png)
What did I miss?

Comment: file.readAsBytes() try this

Comment: The request failed because the file attached to the request is empty. If you look at the sceen capture attached to the question, you can see that length of the file.bytes is 497727 (the length of my selected file)

Comment: The API is written in node js and uses the Multer library to retrieve the file. After several tests, I observe that everything works fine using Postman to send it a file in Multipart Form but from my flutter application it seems that the sending format is not good. Multer does not retrieve a file.

Comment: The req.file object in Multer is undefined when I send the request with the flutter application.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. Without the optional FileName parameter of the fromBytes method the request is not correctly created. You just need to specify a file name for it to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).